# How can i compile .aux files with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

I want to create multiple bibliographies with `multibib` . But the aux files need a special treatment but i dont know how to do it.

An instruction says:
" Compiling your main document .tex will generate multiple .aux files. You must now run bibtex on all these .aux files, before compiling the main document .tex file again."

How to run Bibtex on them? Can i do it in TexMaker or not?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! One simple way would be using `latexmk` so it will take care of  all these things for you. // If you do not use latexmk, following the message's instructions, you need `bibtex xxx` where the aux file is named `xxx.aux` for all generated aux files.

Comment: You can do this by going to Options -> Configure TeXmaker -> Quickbuild -> User -> Wizard, and then adding the commands in succession. You can also do this manually by separating adjacent commands with a vertical bar. Good luck!